# how to export variables back to the parent process

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm try to export variables back to the parent process.

```
$ export VAR=FALSE
$ echo $VAR
FALSE

$ ./myprogram  # this will set VAR=TRUE
$ echo $VAR
TRUE  <========== I want to print `TRUE` here
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't be done. The only reliable way to pass anything to the parent process is to echo it and have the parent process capture it with command substitution.

```
VAR=$(./myprogram)
```

Comment: I think some programs even have options to format their output accordingly.

Comment: Depends what you mean with reliable. Named pipes are a pretty reliable way, without race conditions.

Comment: The easiest way is to echo `var=value` couples in the child and call `eval $(./myprogram)`.

Comment: how do you do this with an array, e.g. `echo "$@"`?

Comment: This is not the only way, answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process/502129#502129

Answer (score 5):

Actually... I got this to work just now using `source`

If `myprogram` contains:

```
export VAR=TRUE
```

then after running `source myprogram` your case will work.

Comment: This should work even without `export`, but it should be explicitly stated it doesn't answer the literal question. `source` doesn't create a child, there is no child here, the original `bash` is not a parent process.

Comment: You did not export variables to the parent process, you included them in the *current* process, as `source` works like "including a file".  It could help some cases, but it's not a solution to the question "how to export variables back to the parent process".

Comment: I'm with @KamilMaciorowski  `source doesn't create a child, there is no child here`