# How to properly add preffered directory with duplicate binary to PATH?

Tags: linux, path

I need to use prebuilt binaries to compile Android from source.
The problem is, that seems like it's using the binaries I do not want it to use.
As far as I understand gcc from the first directory in PATH that contains gcc will be used. But it's not.

This is my script for overriding PATH

```
#!/bin/bash

# The directory from which I want to use gcc, c++ etc
export PATH=/run/media/doctor/temporary/C811_Build_ICS/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/arm-eabi/bin

# Other stuff that I need
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/19.0.0/
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java6/bin:/opt/java6/db/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java6/jre/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-ndk
```

These are the contents of the toolchain directory

```
$ ls -1 /run/media/doctor/temporary/C811_Build_ICS/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/arm-eabi/bin
ar
as
c++
g++
gcc
ld
nm
objcopy
objdump
ranlib
strip
```

Now I run

```
$ ./toolchain.sh 
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

And get the gcc that I don't want.

Comment: You need to use `source ./toolchain.sh` or (equivalent `. ./toolchain.sh`). Otherwise a new bash instance is spawned (where the variables are set), but this instance exists immediately... hence you lose the new settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` command exports variables to new processes created from your current shell, but it does not export them to "parent" processes / shells.

You can take a look to these threads for more information:

- [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)
- [how to export variables back to the parent process](https://superuser.com/questions/369732/how-to-export-variables-back-to-the-parent-process)

You should source your file (it does not have to be an executable file), instead of running it:

```
$ source toolchain
```